# iOS Pinterest API

Tags: ios, cocoa, sdk, pinterest

I am using the pinterest SDK to post images to pinterest. However I can not figure out which data I need to pass for the arguments "withSuccess" and "andFailure" on calling the following method within my app?

```
-(void)createPinWithImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL link:(NSURL *)link onBoard:(NSString *)boardId description:(NSString *)pinDescription withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are callbacks - functions you write that get called when the post succeeds or fails.
For example, from [Pinterest's documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/), here's how you'd call a similar method with success and failure callbacks:

```
[[PDKClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"me/"
                    parameters:nil
                   withSuccess:^(PDKResponseObject *responseObject) {
                       // success actions - the code you write here will
                       // be called if the call succeeds.
                       // responseObject will contain information about
                       // the result of the call.
                   } andFailure:^(NSError *error) {
                       // failure actions - the code you write here will
                       // be called if the call fails. error will give
                       // you information about why the call failed.
                   }];
```

The callbacks are a type of object called a "block" in Objective C. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) is a reasonable place to start learning about blocks, but there are plenty of other tutorials out there.